# barcodescanner plugin issue in phonegap project

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, barcode-scanner

I have tried [barcodescanner.js samples](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner/Example) for my phonegap project which need Qrcode reader, the sample project provided works fine in xcode. Problem arises when iam trying to develop an independent project.

- my config.xml has:

`<plugin name="com.cordova.barcodeScanner" value="CDVBarcodeScanner" />`

- iam using: phonegap 2.7.0
- i have included `barcodescanner.js` and its tag properly.

my code:

```
function onDeviceReady()
                {
                    // do your thing!
                    navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");

                    scanButton = document.getElementById("scan-button");
                    resultSpan = document.getElementById("scan-result");

                    scanButton.addEventListener("click", clickScan, false);
                    createButton.addEventListener("click", clickCreate, false);

                }
                  function clickScan() {
                      alert("clickScan");
                    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(scannerSuccess, scannerFailure);
                }


                function scannerSuccess(result) {
                    console.log("scannerSuccess: result: " + result)
                    resultSpan.innerText = "success: " + JSON.stringify(result)
                }

                function scannerFailure(message) {
                    console.log("scannerFailure: message: " + message)
                    resultSpan.innerText = "failure: " + JSON.stringify(message)
                }
```

it is ok till the alert; "clickscan",

after that nothing happens (what prevents my                         `window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(scannerSuccess, scannerFailure);`working).

This is how my project looks like-->
[image]

Iam struggling with this for two days and i checked almost all questions on "barcodescanner" tag in SO, did'nt solved my issue, need your help..  Thanks.

Comment: Have you added CDVBarcodeScanner.mm and zxing-all-in-one.cpp/.h to CordovaLib/Plugins? What would `alert( typeof window.plugins.barcodeScanner )` show in your `clickScan` function?

Comment: yeah... it all there..  alert( typeof window.plugins.barcodeScanner ); not showing anything.

Comment: @pawel: Is there anything other i have to config? (also look @ my project tree).

Comment: barcodescanner.js should be somehere in `www` folder. Add `alert('barcode plugin js loaded')` in the first line of barcodescanner.js to be sure it's properly included.

Comment: The very first line of the file. if it's not alerting it means the file is not referenced properly. How do you include it in your html file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39997/discussion-between-mvp-and-pawel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config.xml you have:

```
<plugin name="com.cordova.barcodeScanner" value="CDVBarcodeScanner" />
```

But in barcodescanner.js from the zip archive linked in your question it's called like this:

```
Cordova.exec(successWrapper, fail, "org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner", "scan", options);
```

So try changing the line in your config.xml to

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner" value="CDVBarcodeScanner" />
```

After more investigation it's been estabilished that the barcodescanner.js from example .zip was written for older version of Phonegap and was incompatible with 2.7. [Here's a version](http://pastebin.com/fyqXnqtS) I use with 2.7 and 2.9, requires `<plugin name="BarcodeScanner" value="CDVBarcodeScanner" />` in config.xml and can be called like this:

```
var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/barcodescanner"); 
scanner.scan(scannerSuccess, scannerFailure);
```

Comment: What if you use the cordova-1.5.0.js from zip archive instead of 2.7? It may use different plugin definition methods. The source doesn't look like barcodescanner.js I have used with phonegap 2.7 and 2.9.